# how to transfer a unique_ptr from a priority queue to a queue

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

In "short", I have a `priority_queue` selecting k `unordered_set<int>` satisfying certain condition. I'd like to return them (the hash sets) as a `queue`.

Since the creation and maintainence of a `priority_queue` expects element swap, I use a pointer instead of `unordered_set<int>` as the entry of the `priority_queue`.

Hence the return type should be `queue< smart_ptr<unordered_set<int>> >`.

If I use `shared_ptr` the code works fine, but I wish to use `unique_ptr` since it is more economic and the clients promise to use it as a `unique_ptr`.

How to use `unique_ptr` to implement the following code?

-------------------Detailed discription-------------------------------

I have a function to read from a file retain `k` lines that have sizes closest to a reference size. Say, if `k=2`, the reference size is `5`, and the file contains 6 lines with sizes (number of integers in this line) `3,5,6,20,2,1`. The `k-closest` lines are the two lines at size `5` and `6` respectively.

I use a `priority_queue` of size `k` with customized comparator to achieve the goal. I decide to return a `queue` containing the selected `k-closest` lines, since the clients do not want to know how a comparator is implemented (the comparator is an argument to the `priority_queue` template).

```
using ptr_type = shared_ptr<unordered_set<int>>;
// ???????????????????????????????????????
// using ptr_type = unique_ptr<unordered_set<int>>; // unique_ptr does not work
// ???????????????????????????????????????
// Is it possible to transfer unique_ptr entries from a priority_queue to a queue?
using pair_comm_type = pair<int,ptr_type>;

queue<pair_comm_type> f() {
    // myFile.txt is a space separated file of integers.
    // Different lines may have different lengths (number of integers)
  string inputFile = "myFile.txt";
  const int TOP_K_LINE = 3;

    // to open a file
  ifstream fin(inputFile.c_str());
  string readBuffer;
  // The file opened

    // to define a priority_queue
    // define customized compare function, such that retained lines have size
    // closest to the reference value.
  double referenceSize = log10(10.0);
  auto comp = [&referenceSize](const pair_comm_type &LHS, const pair_comm_type &RHS)
      { return abs(log10(LHS.first)-referenceSize) 
      < abs(log10(RHS.first)-referenceSize); };
  priority_queue<pair_comm_type, vector<pair_comm_type>, decltype(comp)> myHeap(comp);
  // the priority_queue defined

  int bufIntValue = -1;
  int curMinArraySize = -1; // auxilliary variable, to reduce heap top access
    // to read the file line by line
  while (getline(fin,readBuffer)) {
      // to read int in each line to a hash set
    istringstream S(readBuffer);
    ptr_type lineBufferPtr(new unordered_set<int>);
    while (S>>bufIntValue) lineBufferPtr->insert(bufIntValue);
// one line read

      // to decide retain or not based on the length of this line
    int arraySize = lineBufferPtr->size();
    if (myHeap.size() < TOP_K_LINE) {
      // We can add new lines as long as top-k is not reached
      myHeap.emplace(arraySize,std::move(lineBufferPtr));
      curMinArraySize = myHeap.top().first;
      continue;
    }
    if (arraySize <= curMinArraySize) continue;
    myHeap.emplace(arraySize,std::move(lineBufferPtr));
    myHeap.pop();
    curMinArraySize = myHeap.top().first;
  }
  // all lines read
  fin.close();

    // to transfer values from the priority_queue to a queue
    // ???????????????????????????????????????
    // Is it possible that we can make changes here such that unique_ptr can also work??????
    // ???????????????????????????????????????
  queue<pair_comm_type> Q;
  while (!myHeap.empty()) {
    auto temp = myHeap.top();
    myHeap.pop();
    Q.emplace(temp.first,std::move(temp.second));
  }

  /*
  while (!Q.empty()) {
    printf("%d, ",Q.front().first);
    Q.pop();
  }
  printf("\n");
  */
  return Q;
}
```

Comment: *"Since the creation and maintainence of a priority_queue expects element swap, I use a pointer instead of unordered_set<int> as the entry of the priority_queue."* - is that really necessary? `unordered_set<int>` can be swapped/moved.

Comment: Sounds like you would need to call .release() on the element in the priority_queue before removing it (so the PQ doesn't delete the pointer). You _might_ be able to do: unique_ptr<T> tmp = std::move(pq.front()); pq.pop(); return tmp; but I haven't looked to see whether unique_ptr is moveable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STL` containers are designed to be *moved* and when you do so it is just as efficient as using *pointers*. In fact they use *pointers* internally so you don't have to.

I would consider just using values like this:

```
using pair_comm_type = pair<int, unordered_set<int>>;

queue<pair_comm_type> f() {

  string inputFile = "myFile.txt";
  const int TOP_K_LINE = 3;

  ifstream fin(inputFile.c_str());
  string readBuffer;

  double referenceSize = log10(10.0);
  auto comp = [&referenceSize](const pair_comm_type &LHS, const pair_comm_type &RHS)
      { return abs(log10(LHS.first)-referenceSize)
      < abs(log10(RHS.first)-referenceSize); };
  priority_queue<pair_comm_type, vector<pair_comm_type>, decltype(comp)> myHeap(comp);

  int bufIntValue = -1;
  int curMinArraySize = -1;

  while (getline(fin,readBuffer)) {
    istringstream S(readBuffer);

    // no need to use pointers here
    unordered_set<int> lineBufferPtr;
    while (S>>bufIntValue)
        lineBufferPtr.insert(bufIntValue);

    int arraySize = lineBufferPtr.size();
    if (myHeap.size() < TOP_K_LINE) {

      myHeap.emplace(arraySize,std::move(lineBufferPtr));
      curMinArraySize = myHeap.top().first;
      continue;
    }
    if (arraySize <= curMinArraySize) continue;
    myHeap.emplace(arraySize,std::move(lineBufferPtr));
    myHeap.pop();
    curMinArraySize = myHeap.top().first;
  }

  fin.close();

  // Use std::move to transfer the top() element which will be
  // just as efficient as using pointers

  queue<pair_comm_type> Q;

  while (!myHeap.empty()) {
    auto temp = std::move(myHeap.top()); // USE MOVES
    myHeap.pop();
    Q.push(std::move(temp));
  }

  return Q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Galik 's solution works.

As for the original question, the simple answer is NO. We can not transfer a unique_ptr out of a priority_queue.

The [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/) of `unique_ptr`, of which the argument is a const reference, is deleted. The return type of `priority_queue::top()` is a [const reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/). Hence we cannot use the return value to create a new `unique_ptr` object.